# Need SQL tuning ideas: query taking very long time

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

SQL tuning: I have one script which have 3 create table statement : one is being created from the same table with two new columns added and other two are temp tables creation statement and 2 update statements, last time when I ran the query it took 13 hours to complete. I already have index on the columns, using parallel and full hints. my create tables have group by, filtering data from two columns from two very big tables.. What should be my first step to tune this query? should I take one create table code, run it manually and see how long it is taking and then decide what to use i.e, hint or something? Need an approach to start my steps...

Comment: At a minimum, you need to post the query and the explain plan in order to provide enough information to get informed answers.

Comment: explain plan for
CREATE TABLE AR1_CREDIT_DEBIT_LINK_DOX PARALLEL 4 NOLOGGING AS
SELECT /*+PARALLEL(A,4) FULL(A) */
     A.* ,
     TO_DATE(NULL) L3_CDL_CREATION_DATE ,
     TO_DATE(NULL) L3_CDL_REVERSAL_DATE
FROM AR1_CREDIT_DEBIT_LINK A;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Comment: ID                                                                                       COST
|   0 | CREATE TABLE STATEMENT |           |   510M|    47G|   234K|            

|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL | AR1_CREDIT_DEBIT_LINK     |   510M|    47G|   122K|     1 |   862 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |

Comment: @Allan  Apologies not formatted: for above create statement the cost for CREATE TABLE stmnt is 234k and  cost for "5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL | AR1_CREDIT_DEBIT_LINK  " is 122k

Comment: don't post your explain in a comment, edit your original question and post it THERE.

Comment: You should put all of this into the question, not comments. Use the "edit" link under the question.

Comment: Is that a table over a database link?

Answer (score 0):

Why no permanently create the tables? You can just wipe them as the first step in your script? Just create them in your local schema and not the program schema. We do that do reports that take a while to run that we have to run quarterly.